# Cannot append values from a function

Tags: python, list

I write a function to evaluate sentiments in the column of a `dataframedata_tweets['text']`: negative, positive or neutral attitude in the sentence, and I try to append the output into a list because I want to add the sentiments into an original dataframe

My function:

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer 

# function to print sentiments 
# of the sentence. 
def sentiment_scores(sentence): 

    # Create a SentimentIntensityAnalyzer object. 
    sid_obj = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() 

    # polarity_scores method of SentimentIntensityAnalyzer 
    # oject gives a sentiment dictionary. 
    # which contains pos, neg, neu, and compound scores. 
    sentiment_dict = sid_obj.polarity_scores(sentence) 
    print("Sentence Overall Rated As",end = " ") 

    # decide sentiment as positive, negative and neutral 
    if sentiment_dict['compound'] >= 0.05 : 
        print("Positive") 

    elif sentiment_dict['compound'] <= - 0.05 : 
        print("Negative") 

    else : 
        print("Neutral")
```

Outputs:

```
Neutral
Neutral
Positive
Neutral
Neutral
```

Here is what I write to append the list, but when I print `tweet_sentiment_vader`, I only get `None`. Can anyone tell me why I cannot successfully append the value to an empty list?

```
tweet_sentiment_vader = []
row_count=data_tweets.shape[0]

for i in range(row_count):
    sent = data_tweets['text'][i]
    tweet_sentiment_vader.append(sentiment_scores(sent))
```

Comment: Your function `sentiment_scores` doesn't **return** anything - it only `print`s the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering returning a value

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer 

# function to print sentiments 
# of the sentence. 
def sentiment_scores(sentence): 

    # Create a SentimentIntensityAnalyzer object. 
    sid_obj = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() 

    # polarity_scores method of SentimentIntensityAnalyzer 
    # oject gives a sentiment dictionary. 
    # which contains pos, neg, neu, and compound scores. 
    sentiment_dict = sid_obj.polarity_scores(sentence) 
    print("Sentence Overall Rated As",end = " ") 

    # decide sentiment as positive, negative and neutral 
    if sentiment_dict['compound'] >= 0.05 : 
        value = "Positive" 

    elif sentiment_dict['compound'] <= - 0.05 : 
        value  = "Negative"

    else : 
        value = "Neutral"

    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try building and returning a list instead:

```
def sentiment_scores(sentence): 

    local_tweet_sentiment_vader = []
    # Create a SentimentIntensityAnalyzer object. 
    sid_obj = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() 

    # polarity_scores method of SentimentIntensityAnalyzer 
    # oject gives a sentiment dictionary. 
    # which contains pos, neg, neu, and compound scores. 
    sentiment_dict = sid_obj.polarity_scores(sentence) 
    print("Sentence Overall Rated As",end = " ") 

    # decide sentiment as positive, negative and neutral 
    if sentiment_dict['compound'] >= 0.05 : 
        print("Positive") 
        local_tweet_sentiment_vader.append("Positive")

    elif sentiment_dict['compound'] <= - 0.05 : 
        print("Negative") 
        local_tweet_sentiment_vader.append("Negative")
    else : 
        print("Neutral") 
        local_tweet_sentiment_vader.append("Neutral")
    return local_tweet_sentiment_vader
```

Print statements are not going to be appened into a list